# Does StageWebView work on Desktop devices?

Tags: actionscript-3, air, adobe, desktop, stagewebviewbridge

I need to create an Windows application that opens up a website in StageWebView. When I test it out in Flash IDE - it opens up correctly. When I publish it to *.exe file, all I see is a blank flash file.

Can someone tell me if StageWebView supports Desktop devices and if yes, how to publish it correctly?

Comment: have you [checked the documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/media/StageWebView.html)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

StageWebView works on desktop so long as you're publishing as AIR. If you're just using the export to EXE feature it won't work as you're basically just packaging the normal web Flash Player with your SWF file and don't have access to the extended API's that AIR does.

So, just make sure to change your Publish Settings to publish as an AIR app and you should be good.